# Can I Use a List To Position An Arbitrary Number of Graphic Objects?

Tags: graphics, map

I can use a function to compute the positions of individual nodes of a neural network based on how many there are in each layer (nodesPerLayerList below). Now I want to display them all in position. The Map function below does put out the requested number of circles, but does not position them. The multiple Graphics examples in the hands-on start book type out each object explicitly.

Is there a simple way? Must I loop?

```
nodesPerLayerList = { 2 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 1  } ;
nodeCenterList = positionNodes[ nodesPerLayerList ] ;
nodeCenterList 

(* 
  {{{10,30},4},{{10,42},4},{{24,18},4},{{24,30},4},{{24,42},4},
  {{24,53},4},{{38,24},4},{{38,36},4},{{38,48},4},{{52,18},4},{{52,30},4},
  {{52,42},4},{{52,53},4},{{65,36},4},{{79,36},4}}
*)
```

And then

```
Map[ Graphics[ Circle[] ] , nodeCenterList ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE and thank you for taking the time to format your post correctly even in your first question ever. Just in case you don't know already: When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh) because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! If you have questions about a solution, you can comment on it.

Comment: Thank you to both halirutan and henrik for your very welcoming and helpful responses. I am off to summer school in a couple weeks and am, in the mean time, renewing my acquaintance with the top row of my keyboard, all too often with a pinkie on the shift key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map` was already very close. Try `Graphics[Circle @@@ nodeCenterList]` (have a look at `Apply` to understand what is happening). Try also `Map[Circle ,nodeCenterList]` and observe that there will be too many braces. `Apply` gets rid of them by replacing them.

Note also that `Circle[]` stands for the unit circle centered at `{0,0}`.

In the end, just wrap a `Graphics` around all graphics primitives. You can also join `Graphics` with `Show`.

Comment: The three at-signs worked a treat. i was hoping that they would do the same for the links between the circles. They did not. There are three dozen link lines of which the first few that i am getting are:

Comment: So, what are they? =D `Line` always wants to get a list of points. In this case, `Map` is more suitable, e.g., `Line /@ {{{10, 30}, {10, 42}}, {{38, 48}, {52, 18}}}` (like `@@@` is the infix form of `Apply`, `/@` is the infix form of `Map`.

Comment: hello henrik. i tried to include them but apparently timed out at five minutes. the first three i get are:
{{{13.56,27.4},{20.70,20.23}},{{14.00,30.00},{20.00,30.00}},{{13.56,32.6},{20.70,39.77}}}

Comment: Hi James, I see what you are about to do. You can also reference the vertices by their position in the list `nodeCenterList` and extract the midpoints automatically like this. If you plot the vertices as white `Disk`s on top of the edges, you don't have to compute the points where an edge meets the circles: `edges = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}};
edgepts = Partition[nodeCenterList[[Flatten[edges], 1]], 2];
Graphics[{
  Line /@ edgepts,
  EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[White], Disk @@@ nodeCenterList
  }]`

Comment: You might also be interested in `Graph` (with `VertexCoordinates` set to ). That's the datatype specific for to networks and there are many styling options. Here an example: `Graph[
 Range[Length[nodeCenterList]],
 edges,
 VertexCoordinates -> nodeCenterList[[All, 1]],
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Disk[#1, 4] &),
 VertexStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Red],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Line[#1] &),
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black],
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Italic, 14]
 ]`

Comment: These are both very fruitful approaches; thank you. it will take me a day to absorb them since i am new to the wolfram language. My present interest is in building a small WL version of an educational app i already have (in a language nobody has heard of) that allows the user to mouse over a node and get a larger version of it that tells what is going on inside that particular node. Big node or small, the links all have arrowheads that show the direction of the data flow (back prop. goes the other way, of course.) That is what got me to edge-to-edge links.

Comment: Btw., you can also have `Graph`s with `DirectedEdge`s. And also `Mouseover` will be of interest, but you will probably know it already. I wish you good progress in your endeavor!